maui ios copy files from selected directory in ios
I want to copy files from selected directory to application directory.
So I`m use folder picker from Community toolkit
var result = await FolderPicker.Default.PickAsync(cancellationToken);

if (result.IsSuccessful)
{
path = result.Folder.Path;
}

After that i try to get list of files in this directory
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*")

And this cause error:
Access to the path "SelectedFolderPath" is denied.
On the ios simulator this works without errors. How to fix it? Maybe i need to write some permissions in info.plist file (lik android in manifest file) for this action?

You cannot write files to this path by code directly.
If you want to write a file in the Files application in iOS platform.
Firstly, Enable iCloud capabilities. For more information, please check: iOS capabilities and Enable Share with Files app.
Then, if I have an image that in the /Resources/Image folder, I want to write it to the Files application. We can do as follows:
1.we can copy it to the application internal storage.
 public async Task CopyFileToAppDataDirectory(string filename)
    {
        // Open the source file
        using Stream inputStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filename);

       // Create an output filename
        string targetFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, filename);
       // Copy the file to the AppDataDirectory
        using FileStream outputStream = File.Create(targetFile);
        await inputStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
    }

2.then we can share this file to Files app. It will push a popup window, please choose Save to Files selection.
public async Task ShareFile()
{
    string fn = "test.png";
    string file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, fn);
    await Share.Default.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
    {
        Title = "Share text file",
        File = new ShareFile(file)
    });
}


Ok. But how to get filename from folder /Resources/Image as example?

The filename is the name of the image you want to get. You can specify this in your code.
